# Post install script within nodejs process doesn't recognize node path

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have some node.js code I'm running in a NodeJS process that I generate a package.json and I perform an NPM install like so:

```
import childProcess from "child_process";

const exec = childProcess.exec;

const { stderr, stdout } = await exec(`${process.execPath} npm install`, {
      env: {
        'PATH': process.execPath,
      } 
    });
```

The npm install works, but the post install script doesn't. and it outputs the following:

```
npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall ~/project/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried adding the `process.execPath` to be set to the PATH variable of my NodeJS process but that didn't seem to work. I know `process.execPath` allows me to get the node process that started the process, but I also want to use it to invoke the post install scripts.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions the error message gave you? `Use the --scripts-prepend-node-path option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.`

Comment: @tkausl yeah I tried, it doesn't work. I get an error saying:

36427 verbose stack Error: core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
36427 verbose stack spawn sh ENOENT
36427 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
36427 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
36427 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)